# Usergrid collection Last In First Out

Tags: collections, usergrid, lifo

The default behavior for usergrid collection seems to be the entities that were added first are retrieved first when doing a GET. Can I have the entities retrieved in the reverse order, i.e. the entities added last are retrieved first. I know I can do it using a query ql=select * order by created desc but will this always mean sorting the results (having performance implications) ?

For e.g 
If I have a usergrid collection of Blogs then I need to get the latest blog first without having to do order by.

How do we achieve this ?

Comment: Using order by is the only way to achieve this.  However, you shouldn't suffer any significant performance hit using order by.  Are you seeing performance problems using it?

Comment: Thanks @rockerston for your reply. I assumed that using a order by especially if the collection has a large number of rows would result in degraded performance due to the additional sorting that we do on the results. I have not compared the performance of the plain query versus the order by query.

Comment: If you are using 1.0, then there will be a performance hit, especially with a query.  2.0 uses ElasticSearch so the impact is not as significant.

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of ElasticSearch in the 2.x architecture order by ascending can be achieved with decent performance.  Please try this per the documentation here: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/querying-your-data